# create macro to verbatim output of command

Tags: macros, verbatim

The code

```
\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{#1 #1}
\expandafter\verb\expandafter+\dosomething{blub}+
```

produces the verbatim-output `blub blub`.

Now I want to create a macro `\myverb` for the second line, i.e., I want that

```
\myverb{blub}
```

or

```
\myverb+blub+
```

creates the verbatim-output `blub blub`.

How can I achieve this (in TeX or LaTeX)?

A follow up question is, how to achieve it with a `verbatim`-environment instead of `\verb`? Here a concrete example:

```
\begin{verbatim}
  \begin{evaluatecode}
     a = 1+1
     b = 2^a
     print a,b
  \end{evaluatecode}
\end{verbatim}
```

But I want that the environment `evaluatecode` is expanded first (in my case, the calculations are sent to some software, an output is returned; `evaluatecode` already exists), and then, the result is displayed in verbatim. I.e., I want that the code

```
\begin{verbatimevaluate}
     a = 1+1
     b = 2^a
     print a,b
\end{verbatimevaluate}
```

does the following: first the input of `verbatimevaluate` is processed by the `evaluatecode`-environment and its outcome stands in an `verbatim`-environment.

Comment: Do you *really* need `\verb` for printing control sequence names and other special characters, or do you just need `\texttt`? I believe that the *real* application is different, isn't it?

Comment: `\texttt` does not work, I really need `\verb`. (The real application comes from using the `sagetex`-package, which is used for interaction with the computer algebra system Sage.)

Comment: It still isn't very clear, I'm afraid. What do you mean by “doubling a `verbatim` environment”?

Comment: i wonder about the statement “`\texttt` does not work, I really need `\verb`” ... given that we have no example of what you are aiming for, we have to guess what you're doing that forces out `\texttt`

Comment: "doubling" was just an example-function `\doit` (a function that manipulates its input in some way).

Comment: Here a concrete example: I have a command (from the `sagetex`-package) like `\sagestr{Set((1,2))}` which returns the string `{1,2}`. I want to display this output verbatim. That is a simple example; in general the output can contain various special symbols like `$`, `_`, ... (I could find one that is not used for `\verb`). Therefore `\texttt` does not work. What I want is to call something like `\verbsagestr{Set((1,2))}`, which produces the correct output.

Comment: edit: I formulated the former last line (how to do it with `verbatim`) more precisely. Further, I rephrased the question to exclude "double", which was misleading.

Comment: Sorry, but the last paragraph is utterly obscure.

Comment: Sorry for that. I tried to rewrite the last paragraph. Please tell me when it is still not understandable.

Comment: The word `output` is not clear. If you have problems with `$`, `{`, `_`, I guess it means they are produced with their standard catcodes? is this done expandably? then `\detokenize` and suitable `\expandafter`'s could do what you want. Do you have only one macro to expand, or as your multiline examples suggest more than one? where should this expansion stop? I think your question is still formulated in a too general way, so it's hard to address it as we may spend times on delicate issues (e.g. how to counteract `TeX`'s handling of end of lines) which could well be irrelevant.

Comment: I rewrote it and gave a conrete example. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @DanielKrenn No, sorry, it's not clear; what you need is interaction between LaTeX and some software, which depends on the software; loading the output produced by the external software as a verbatim listing is easy.

Comment: Let me clearify that: The environment `evaluatecode` already exists and deals with the external software. You can see it as a blackbox that transforms its input into output. All I want is now to display that output properly (respecting all possible symbols).

Comment: BTW: The first part of my question (`\myverb`) is already answered by jfbu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**: you *may* upvote this answer `;-)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\myverb 
{%
  \relax\leavevmode\null
  \bgroup 
  \verbatim@font
  \let\do\do@noligs  \verbatim@nolig@list
  \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
  \@vobeyspaces
  \@myverb 
}% 
\def\@myverb #1{\catcode`#1\active
                \lccode`\~`#1%
                \lowercase{\long\def~##1~}{\myverbaction{##1}\egroup}%
                \lowercase{~}}%
\makeatother


% customize as desired:
\newcommand{\myverbaction}[1]{#1 #1}%

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\myverb+blub+

\myverb+\if\end&^_~%$   \par\ifcase+

\myverb|some +-$^%_

  multiline

input|
\end{document}
```

[image: my verb1]

---

For better rendering of multiline things, something like the following (else one may follow more closely the `LaTeX` own `verbatim`).

```
\def\myverb 
{%
  \relax\leavevmode\null
  \bgroup 
  \verbatim@font
  \let\do\do@noligs  \verbatim@nolig@list
  \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
  \@vobeyspaces
% in case of multi-line input, something like this:
  \obeylines\parskip\baselineskip \parindent\z@
  \@myverb 
}%
```

[image: my multiline verb]

This used a `\noindent` which was not there in the first image (everything was indented in the first image, but the indentation was trimmed when converting to
a `png`).

```
\noindent\myverb|some +-$^%_

  multiline

input|
```

Comment: Doubling the argument is trivial with `xparse`. The problem is that we don't know what the OP really wants.

Comment: `\frenchspacing` should be added to `\myverb`, as I most of the time have it by default in my documents, I didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 4):

***Note: please, don't vote for this answer, which is actually a large comment that can't be in comments; it is aimed to a clarification of the question***

With `xparse` you can define commands that absorb their argument verbatim:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\verbsagestr}{v}{%
  \texttt{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\verbsagestr{Str($1,2_3)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can manipulate the argument in various ways, but without any specification it's quite difficult to say more.

The part of your question about `verbatim` is really unclear.

Comment: Still need to +1 for making it clear. :)

Comment: what can we do to stop you getting upvotes? even explicit request is not obeyed! `:)`

Comment: I tried to rewrite the `verbatim`-paragraph.